# Add digits of a number together and return the sum

Tags: javascript, digits

A homework question I need help with.

I have to find the sum of the num added together.

```
function getSumOfDigits(num) {
    //What goes here?
}

console.log(getSumOfDigits(42), '<-- should be 6');

console.log(getSumOfDigits(103), '<-- should be 4');
```

The answer should be basic considering this is beginner javascript.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: what about negative numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Turn the number into a string with `toString`, `split` it and `reduce` the array:

```js
function getSumOfDigits(num) {
  return [...num.toString()].reduce((acc, curr) => +acc + +curr);
}

console.log(getSumOfDigits(42));
console.log(getSumOfDigits(103));
```

Comment: or `.reduce((acc, curr) => +acc + +curr)` (one less iteration)

Answer (score 2):

You could go over the number dividing by 10 and use modulus 10 to extract the last digit :

```js
function getSumOfDigits(num) {
    let sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += (num % 10);
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(getSumOfDigits(42))
console.log(getSumOfDigits(102))
```

Comment: This is good approach IMO instead of changing to string than split than looping and again changing back to numbers. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can  modulus (%) 10 to get the last digit.Then,add that digit to sum.
After adding to sum,trim last digit from value.

```js
var value = 123456,
    sum = 0;

while (value) {
    sum += value % 10;
    value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive approach, by taking the last number off the `num` each call and adding it with a call to the sum of integers from 0 to n-1 (where `n` is the amount of digits in the number)

See example below:

```js
const getSumOfDigits = num => 
  num < 10 ? num : num%10 + getSumOfDigits(~~(num / 10))

console.log(getSumOfDigits(42), '<-- should be 6');
console.log(getSumOfDigits(103), '<-- should be 4');
```

The above function works like so, for this example, I'll let the input `num` be 103:

```
getSumOfDigits(103) = 3 + getSumDigits(10)

getSumOfDigits(10) = 0 + getSumDigits(1)

getSumDigits(1) = 1 // base case hit
```

Once we have hit a call to `getSumDigits` which no longer returns a call to `getSumDigits` we have hit our *base case*, and thus can start working out what our previous calls were. Thus working from the bottom up:

```
getSumDigits(1) = 1

getSumOfDigits(10) = 0 + getSumDigits(1) 1 = 1

getSumOfDigits(103) = 3 + getSumDigits(10) 1 = 4
```

Thus, the result returned will be `4` as seen above.